# SQL statement returning null rather than empty

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query which is:

```
SELECT Player, 
Avg(Case When Score1> 0 then Score1 end) AS AverageScore1, 
Avg(Case When Score2> 0 then Score2 end) AS AverageScore2
FROM scores 
WHERE .... various criteria ...
```

The problem is that this will result set of a single, null record when the criteria is set so that no scores/players should be included.

Is there a way of avoiding getting a null record and the result be empty instead like this example?

[image]

Comment: `HAVING Avg(Case When Score1> 0 then Score1 end) IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Can you give an example of a criteria that would result in not scores being included?

Comment: @Samcd for example albeit a silly one WHERE Player='xxx' and there is no Player called xxx

Comment: @RichardGriffiths then probably the `ISNULL` answer will work

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `ISNULL` function around the column.

```
ISNULL(Avg(Case When Score1> 0 then Score1 end),'')
```

If the first parameter returns a NULL value, it will be replaced by the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "empty" when you are dealing with numeric values.  The closest you can come is `NULL`, which is what your expression returns.

If you want a `NULL` value, then you should convert the value *explicitly* to a string.  This is important for formatting reasons.  You don't specify the database you are using; most databases have a way of formatting a number.

The idea is something like:

```
SELECT Player, 
       COALESCE(CAST(Avg(Case When Score1 > 0 then Score1 end) as VARCHAR(255)), '') AS AverageScore1, 
       COALESCE(CAST(Avg(Case When Score2 > 0 then Score2 end) as VARCHAR(255)), '') AS AverageScore2
FROM scores 
WHERE .... various criteria ...
GROUP BY Player;
```

The `cast()` is just a placeholder for your preferred method of outputting a string, if you decide to go down this route.

Comment: If you see my edit you will see what I mean by empty. I realise that there may be a difference between SQL and MySQL. Edited tag.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths . . . Add `group by player`.   That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the table setup similar to this:

```
create table scores(
  Player varchar(20) not null,
  score1 int not null,
  score2 int not null
);
```

And your data similar to this:

```
insert into scores(player, score1, score2) values('player 1', 0, 0);
insert into scores(player, score1, score2) values('player 1', 10, 20);
insert into scores(player, score1, score2) values('player 1', 20, 30);
```

And when you run the query with criteria similar to this:

```
SELECT Player, 
    Avg(Case When Score1> 0 then Score1 end) AS AverageScore1, 
    Avg(Case When Score2> 0 then Score2 end) AS AverageScore2
FROM scores
where Score1<10 and Score2<10
GROUP BY Player
```

You get output like this:

```
Player     AverageScore1    AverageScore2
---------  ---------------  -----------------
Player1    NULL             NULL
```

But what you want is:

```
Player     AverageScore1    AverageScore2
---------  ---------------  -----------------
```

Is that right?

If so, adding a "HAVING" clause will filter out the records with NULLS:

```
SELECT Player, 
    Avg(Case When Score1> 0 then Score1 end) AS AverageScore1, 
    Avg(Case When Score2> 0 then Score2 end) AS AverageScore2
FROM scores
where Score1<10 and Score2<10
GROUP BY Player
having Avg(Case When Score1> 0 then Score1 end) is not null and
    Avg(Case When Score2> 0 then Score2 end) is not null
```